# How to simplify creating an array of objects where except one all properties are same?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```js
const errorMessage = "some error message";
const fieldName = "the field name";

const newFieldRules = [{
    custom: false,
    errorMessage: errorMessage,
    fieldName: fieldName,
    validatorName: `digits`
  },
  {
    custom: false,
    errorMessage: errorMessage,
    fieldName: fieldName,
    validatorName: `min`
  },
  {
    custom: false,
    errorMessage: errorMessage,
    fieldName: fieldName,
    validatorName: `max`
  }
];
```

I need to create the above array. As you can see, few properties are same across all the objects.

Is there any way to improve this code to avoid repetition?

Comment: Write a function that takes a validator name and creates an object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This gets rid of the repetition, using [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
const errorMessage = "some error message";
const fieldName = "the field name";

const newFieldRules = [`digits`, `min`, `max`].map(validatorName => ({
    custom: false,
    errorMessage,
    fieldName,
    validatorName
}));

console.log(newFieldRules);
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably this way:

```js
const errorMessage = "some error message";
const fieldName = "the field name";

const defaultObj = {
    custom: false,
    errorMessage: errorMessage,
    fieldName: fieldName,
}


const newFieldRules = [
    {...defaultObj, validatorName: 'digits'},
    {...defaultObj, validatorName: 'min'},
    {...defaultObj, validatorName: 'max'},
]

console.log(newFieldRules)
```

[Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) was used.

Comment: @Bergi sorry, I still cofuse the terms

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do it using a **reusable `mapper` higher-order function** which takes a mapping structure whose keys will match the output and whose values are either the values to use or a function to generate those values.

The mapper returns a mapping function which can be called with data to generate your output. Here a simple index is used.

Using this pattern you can easily generate complex output while keeping the code succinct since you define `mapper` only once.

```js
const mapper = obj => val => Object.entries(obj).reduce((accum, [key, fnOrVal]) => {
  accum[key] = fnOrVal instanceof Function ? fnOrVal(val) : fnOrVal;
  return accum;
}, {});

const newFieldRulesGenerator = mapper({
    custom: false,
    errorMessage: 'some error message',
    fieldName: 'fieldName',
    validatorName: i => ['digits', 'min', 'max'][i]
});

const newFieldRules = [0, 1, 2].map(newFieldRulesGenerator);

console.log(newFieldRules);
```